# Mod Rewrite htaccess rewriterule

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I now have:

```
Order deny,allow
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine  on
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteRule ^en/newsevents$ ?action=setLang&lang=eng&menuid=6 [L,QSA]
```

It loads my texts but thiks it must look in the /en folder.

This does work, but changes the url from `localhost/en/newsevents` to `localhost/name/?action=setLang&lang=eng&menuid=6`

I want that it still remains `localhost/en/newsevents`

```
RewriteRule ^en/newsevents$ `http://localhost/name/?action=setLang&lang=eng&menuid=6 [L,QSA]`
```

Comment: I now have RewriteRule ^(.+)/newsevents$ ?action=setLang&lang=$1&menuid=6 [L] it does work, but it thinks when i put for (.+)/ -> en that it must look for images in the folder en/img instead of /img

Comment: I've solved the problem by adding the root for each image so instead of img/image.jpg i've /myownroot/img/image.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
RewriteRule ^(en/newsevents)$ $1?action=setLang&lang=eng&menuid=6 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use passthrough

RewriteRule ^en/newsevents$ ?action=setLang&lang=eng&menuid=6 [PT,L,QSA]

Comment: This all works fine:

RewriteRule ^$ home [L]
RewriteRule ^home$ ?action=home [L]
RewriteRule ^compagny$ ?action=bedrijf [L]
RewriteRule ^products$ ?action=producten [L]
RewriteRule ^market$ ?action=markt [L]
RewriteRule ^directsales$ ?action=directeverkoop [L]
RewriteRule ^contact$ ?action=contact [L]
RewriteRule ^en/contact$ ?action=setLang&lang=eng&menuid=7 [L]